# wrong number of args when using forward declared macro

Tags: clojure

I have a function *my-plus-in-macro* that contains a macro named *my-macro*. But *my-macro* is declared after *my-plus-macro* definition. I use **declare** to avoid unable-to-resolve symbol error.

I type these codes in my repl.

```
(declare my-macro my-plus)


(defn my-plus-in-macro [x y]
    (my-macro (my-plus x y)))


(defmacro my-macro [my-fn]
    `~my-fn)


(defn my-plus [x y]
   (+ x y))
```

Then, I expect to get 3 if execute this

```
(my-plus-in-macro 1 2)
```

but instead I get,

```
ArityException Wrong number of args (1) passed to: user$my-macro  clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:437)
```

But, if I execute this *my-plus-in-macro* definition again in the repl

```
(defn my-plus-in-macro [x y]
    (my-macro (my-plus x y)))
```

then I execute this
    (my-plus-in-macro 1 2)

Just what I expect, 3

What happens in my first execution of *(my-plus-in-macro 1 2)*?

Somehow, when I define *my-plus-in-macro* for the first time, clojure sees *my-macro* symbol but it doesn't know yet that I intend to use it as a name for a macro.

Although I have define *my-macro* as a symbol right after I define *my-plus-in-macro*, clojure still doesn't know that *my-macro* is a symbol for a macro. That's why I get ArityException.

But, somehow, when I redefine *my-plus-in-macro* with the same code, Clojure now knows that *my-macro* is a macro and treats it as such and then my code works.

Of course I don't get any exception if I put *my-macro* definition before *my-plus-in-macro* definition. But does that mean I can not use declare to reserve a symbol for a macro?

**EDIT**

based on answer from @xsc, these code works.
I just have to call *my-macro* in *my-plus-in-macro* definition using "correct" way by supplying :form and :env

```
(declare my-macro my-plus)


(defn my-plus-in-macro [x y]
    (my-macro :form :env (my-plus x y)))


(defmacro my-macro [my-fn]
    `~my-fn)


(defn my-plus [x y]
   (+ x y))


(my-plus-in-macro 1 2)
3
```

**EDIT-0**

@xsc you are right, I can not use **declare** to forward-declare symbols for macros. I must put macro definition before any function that use it.

so, this is the right code

```
(declare my-plus)

(defmacro my-macro [my-fn]
    `~my-fn)

(defn my-plus-in-macro [x y]
    (my-macro (my-plus x y)))

(defn my-plus [x y]
   (+ x y))

(my-plus-in-macro 1 2)
3
```

Comment: On your EDIT: This does not "work" in the sense that the macro is now working. You're just calling the underlying function correctly but that means there is no point in having the macro at all. As I said, you cannot forward-declare macros.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Macros are evaluated at compile-time which means the compiler/reader has to know which symbols represent macros and which don't. By simply using `declare` like you do you're not supplying that information which means that instead of replacing the macro call with its evaluated value you'll have a reference to the macro *function* in your code.

In other words: the moment the reader encounters `my-macro` the first time it does not know any better than just leave it there. Since any macro is just a function (with the `:macro` metadata set to `true`) this does not pose a problem once it is defined further below.

You can check this fact by calling the macro function the "correct" way, supplying `&form` and `&env` parameters that would usually be implicitly passed:

```
(declare my-macro)

(defn my-function
  [x]
  (my-macro :form :env x))

(defmacro my-macro
  [x]
  (vector &form &env x))

(my-function (+ 1 2)) ;; => [:form :env 3]
```

Note that the form `(+ 1 2)` is evaluated before being passed to the "macro" since we're dealing with a plain-old function here.

You can declare a symbol as a macro using the aforementioned `:macro` metadata but this will only result in an exception when it is first called since the actual call is before the var is bound to anything:

```
(declare ^:macro my-macro)

(defn my-function
  [x]
  (my-macro x))
;; => IllegalStateException: Attempting to call unbound fn: #'user/my-macro ...
```

**TL;DR:** Declaring a macro will not work since it is called the moment it is encountered by the reader/compiler, no matter how deeply nested inside a function it is.

Comment: Wow! How do you know that the macro needs to be supplied with :form and :env? any reading suggestions?

Comment: too bad, there's no such warning for macro in official *declare* documentation at [http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/declare]

Comment: Note that `&form` usually contains the original macro call and `&env` the environment the call was performed in, and not the two keywords I supplied above. IIRC, the two special symbols were mentioned in [Clojure Programming](http://books.google.de/books?id=nZTvSa4KqfQC&lpg=PA251&dq=clojure%20%26form%20%26env&hl=de&pg=PA251#v=onepage&q&f=false) which was my first Clojure book. I guess it stuck. :)